# Union Don't keep order by

Tags: mysql

```
    (SELECT tag_name  from tags
     WHERE tag_name LIKE '%s%'
     order by case when tag_name ='tags-service' then -1 else 1 end ,tag_name)

    union

    (SELECT email

    from emails
    WHERE email LIKE '%ing%'
    order by case when email='testing@gmail.com' then -1 else 1 end ,email)
```

I am trying to create one table that contains the content of two other tables.
For each table, I would like to order it by the special key.
If table value is equal to the key that I want to put him first, and then after that all the values that contain the special key `('%key%')`.
After that, I would like to order by alphabet all the values that contain my special value (keep the value that equals to my key first).
After each order of the tables I would like to Union the tables.

Table:

```
tag_name:
1.tags-service
2.testing

emails:

3.constanting@gmail.com
4.testing@gmail.com
5.testing1@gmail.com
testingtest@gmail.com
```

I am getting:

```
1.tags-service
2.testing
* 3.constanting@gmail.com *
* 4.testing@gmail.com *
5.testing1@gmail.com
6.testingtest@gmail.com
```

I accept to get:

```
1.tags-service
2.testing
* 3.testing@gmail.com *
* 4.constanting@gmail.com *
5.testing1@gmail.com
6.testingtest@gmail.com
```

Comment: "*use of ORDER BY for individual SELECT statements implies nothing about the order in which the rows appear in the final result because UNION by default produces an unordered set of rows. Therefore, the use of ORDER BY in this context is typically in conjunction with LIMIT, so that it is used to determine the subset of the selected rows to retrieve for the SELECT, even though it does not necessarily affect the order of those rows in the final UNION result.*" Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: to add @MadhurBhaiya 's comment using `ORDER BY column LIMIT 100` can still result into random order where the column has ties..  To bad this is not mentioned in that manual page  also when you need 100% fixed results always you would atleast have to include one column in the ORDER BY clause which has a primary or unique key..

Comment: @RaymondNijland , so If I got you right, I can use `ORDER BY column LIMIT 100` but its a very bad practice. So do you have any other solution? (except of  doing each query and then combine them

Comment: `ORDER BY column LIMIT 100` No it is not bad practice as by ANSI/ISO SQL standard definition resultsets are **unorderd** .. But `ORDER BY column` without using a primary/unique key can result into non deterministic (random) result where column values "ties", imagine if you have  `id|sort` with values`1|2`  and `2|2` and use `ORDER BY sort` on the second column you don't know which id (first column) comes "first" and "last" unless you do `ORDER BY sort, id` assuming id has a primary or unique key..